# Bind collection to Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

I have an object called `Fly`, which has properties `Position` (Point) and `Orientation` (double).
In my MainViewModel I have a collection of my custom object `Fly`called `Flies`.

The View of a fly is a .png image. I want to bind `Flies` to my `Grid` in MainWindow using their properties `Position` and `Orientation` to display the flies on the screen.

I've never done this kind of binding of a collection before. What I did before is bind a collection to a `ListBox` or `ItemsControl`:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ItemView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

How could I bind my objects to a Grid or any other control to be able displaying the right position and angular orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you *shouldn't* set the `ItemsControl.Template` property unless you *actually* want to define a new `ControlTemplate` for it... there is certainly no point in replacing the default `ControlTemplate` with an identical one. Next, your `ItemView` seems pointless if it is just an `Image`... just use an `Image` instead. In this way, you'll be able to data bind your properties properly.

There are several ways to acheive your requirements, but you could use a `RotateTransform` for the `Orientation` and could use a `TranslateTransform` to move the items. Try something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="/Images/Fly.png">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Orientation}" />
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Position.X}"
                            Y="{Binding Position.Y}" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

based on some assumptions from the question here is what you are looking for

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="{Binding Position.X}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Position.Y}" />
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Orientation}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ItemView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What I have done

- set the Canvas as the ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl which will host the items (flies)
- created a style targeting ContentPresenter which is the default host for the items in ContentPresenter.
- binded the Canvas.Left & Canvas.Top to respective Position's X & Y
- added RotateTransform for the orientation and binded the angle to Orientation property.

I can assume that the flies are supposed to fly, so in that case you may want that changing X & Y would change the fly position. but since Point class do not notify the changes to the sub properties, binding may not work as expected. So as a suggestion you may want to create your own Point class with property changed notifications.